# Создание почты пользователя при регистрации

Tags: php, email

Вопрос в чем, скажите алгоритм создание аккаунта почты и связки в базе по логину.
Скажем,  у меня есть 500 свободных ящиков(хостинг предоставляет), домен у меня super.ru,
Почтовые протоколы обычные, **pop3.super.ru**,**smtp.super.ru** (например).
и при регистраций пользователя ,**crazyuser** нужно и создать **crazyuser@super.ru**(ну,ребята, как в жизни при регистрацийй в майл.ру) по логину. Что необходимо сделать? Насчет БД понятно, какие то валидаций,проверки ,потом занесение в таблицу некую.А создание е mail a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> хостинг предоставляет

Хостинг предоставляет доступ только к панели управления хостингом.
По сему ни одного пользователя программно сделать не получиться.
Если был бы свой сервер - то пожалуйста хоть миллион пользователей, а пока на руках "только хостинг" создавать юзверей и почту руками :)

SSH они врядли дают тебе, да и не дадут по ssh выполнить некоторые команды, в том числе добавить пользователя почты ИМХО! Ни один хостер на такое не пойдет. давать место php и мускуль так еще и SSH для того чтобы он тут ваял огромные проекты, для таких целей только выделенные сервера!

Comment: **а пока на руках "только хостинг" создавать юзверей и почту руками**
как это, можно подробнее, плиз? :)

Comment: В панели управления хостингом есть пункт (если конечно есть) создать почтовый ящик.

Answer (score -3):

При регистрации создается домашняя директория для каждого пользователя. В ней делаете почтовый ящик. `...home/username/mail/...`, а там по шаблону входящие, исходящие, и т.д. Но на хостинге, по идее, все это уже должно быть. Или можно так `...tmp/mail/username/...` и в настройках прописываете пути для протоколов, по которым сервер будет это мыло распихивать.

На хостинг кладется готовый сайт, в котором есть форма регистрации (с вопросом создать аккаунт для почты иль нет), в этой форме пользователь заполняет поля, пишет свой логин, который заносится в ($login) и кладется в БД. И при ответе да на вопрос о почте по общему шаблону создается `...home/username=($login)/mail...` или `...tmp/mail/username=($login)...` И все это генерируется PHP'шным скриптом, встроенным в сайт, который мы кладем на хостинг.

Можно взять готовый движок JUMLA, только в ней надо поставить компонент MAIL, ну и возможно подправить скрипты и настройки.

Comment: Приутихните.

Хостеры никогда не дадут програмно создавать почту! БД и реальная почта разные вещи, если впервые слышите, то вам явно следует почитать литературку.

Хостер просто так не даст создать почту из скрипта. На личности прошу не переходить. Почитать вас так вы и слова пишете с ошибками "двигуху JUMLA" так пишут школьники. А компонент mail не даст вам создавать мыльники на хостинге! Так что расслабьтесь и получайте удовольствие.

Comment: @stranger Уважаемый участник, личные замечания на форуме недопустимы.